# Missing FBRequestDelegate when upgrading FBConnect SDK to FacebookSDK 3.0 on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

trying to upgrade existing app that uses FBConnect to FacebookSDK framework 3.0. The xcode compiler is not able to resolve FBRequestDelegate. There is a forward reference @protocol FBRequestDelegate defined in FBRequest.h but there is no matching definition/implementation of that protocol anywhere. Is anyone else having this issue? Documentation indicates it should be there.

Comment: I upgraded last week with no such problem.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from FBRequest.h

An instance of `FBRequest` represents the arguments and setup for a connection to Facebook. After creating an `FBRequest` object it can be used to setup a connection to Facebook through the  object. The  object is created to manage a single connection.

To cancel a connection use the instance method in the  class.

You need to use the new `FBRequestConnection` class to do the requests.
They use an instance of `FBRequest` and a completion handler:

```
- (void)addRequest:(FBRequest*)request completionHandler:(FBRequestHandler)handler;
```